# Trying to parse external json file to create markers in google maps api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am using JavaScript and a external JSON file. 
Here is my JSON file. It is in the same folder as my js file. I called the JSON file csus_locations.JSON

```
{
 "locations": [
 {
    "latitude": 38.558961, 
    "longitude": -121.423011,
    "name": "AIRC",
    "title": "THIS IS WHERE STUFF GETS DONE!"
  },
{
    "latitude": 38.562605, 
    "longitude": -121.419683,
    "name": "GUY WEST",
    "title": "PRESIDENT?"
},
{
    "latitude": 38.556652, 
    "longitude": -121.423842,
    "name": "well",
    "title": "WORKOUT"
  },
{
    "latitude": 38.555465, 
    "longitude": -121.422551,
    "name": "Hornetsatdium",
    "title": "FOOTBAL!"
}

]}
```

I Know that this is legal json code because i tested to verify it. But can i remove "locations": and remove the brackets to make it simpler to parse into google maps?

I am trying to parse the json file using $http.get but my i am note sure if i wrote the code correctly

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['ionic']) 

.controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicLoading, $compile, $ionicPopup, $http) {

    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.5602, -121.4241);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Sac State'
    });

       //i want to get parse with $http.get but i am not sure if i wrote this code correctly
        $http.get('csus_locations.json').success(function(res){
        console.log("success!");
        $scope.locations = res.locations;
        //window.alert("The app is reading the Json file!"); this was a test to see if the get function was working

            var latLng_csus = new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: latLng_csus,
               title: value.name
           });

    });

    /* this was my first attempt to create markers
    console.log(jsonCSUS);
    angular.forEach(jsonCSUS, function(value, key){
        var latLng_csus = new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: latLng_csus,
               title: value.name
           });
           marker.setMap(map);
    });*/


    var onSuccess = function (position) {

        //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
        var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
        var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: compiled[0]
        });

        marker.setPosition(
            new google.maps.LatLng(
                position.coords.latitude,
                position.coords.longitude)
        );


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        $scope.map = map;
        //$scope.map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));


    };

    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
        maximumAge: 3000,
        timeout: 5000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    });

});
```

Comment: do you get any errors in the developer tools console? what does your page do? what do you expect it to do? How does the outcome differ what you expect?

Comment: You don't parse JSON with $Http.Get, you parse JSON with JSON.Parse(), see here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

The provided JSON file, indeed is a valid one, so you could initialize markers like this:

```
$http.get('csus_locations.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.locations = data.locations;

    $scope.locations.forEach(function(item){

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latLng,
           title: item.name,
           map: map
        });

    });

});
```

**Working example**

```js
angular.module('mapApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.5602, -121.4241),
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

 
    $http.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vgrem/c7ec78e7078c2c9ed1c3/raw/959e9d8b8e60544fcc169ea890e84a2624ed8bbb/csus_locations.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.locations = data.locations;

        $scope.locations.forEach(function(item){

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: latLng,
               title: item.name,
               map: map
            });
           
        });
        
    });

});
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&v=3.0&sensor=true"></script> 
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```